Can any line be rotated such that it touches two arbitrary points?
Using one translation and a rotation this can be done.
From the answers there, I assume that one needs the additional translation. But I can't think of an example where this is obvious.
Edit:

To clarify, I am interested in the general 3D case. The 2D/coplanar case is trivial. I hoped that this was clear from the 3d tag, sorry for the confusion.
One is allowed to rotate around an arbitrary point/axis.
I sadly can not give the request further context, I just found this an interesting problem that came to my mind and was not able to solve it myself.


What if the line starts parallel to the segment connecting the two target points? Are you allowed to rotate around a point not on the line?

If you are allowed only rotations (i.e. no translations), then 2 rotations will also do the job, but I guess you are not asking for that obvious answer

@Karl Yes, we are allowed to rotate around any point. Hence, if the line is parallel to the segment connecting the two points, we can rotate around the point that is "in the middle" of the two points and the line by 180 degrees.

From How to ask a good question: "Your question should be clear without the title.
After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

If the line is not parallel to the segment connecting the two points, find the intersection of the line and the line through the two points, and rotate about that point.

Nevermind, I had answered assuming everything was coplanar.

How many rotations are you allowed to do? Only one, or can you do more than one rotation (different centers)?

The interesting case is the case that the two lines (the given line and the line through the two given points) are skew. But remember that two skew lines lie in a unique pair of parallel planes.

The question is not clear. The interesting case is the 3D case, but I'm surmising from all these comments and answers that you meant for this all to be in a plane. Please clarify.

What additional information is needed to reopen this question? I tried to address the points raised in the comments and make the question more clear.  I read "How to ask a good question" and "Provide context" there. But I have a hard time coming up with "additional context", I think the value of this question to me and maybe the community is simply that it might be a interesting one, the additional research I did was thinking about it and searching for an existing answer, both did not yield a result. Please tell me how I can provide additional context

Sometimes a figure is worth a thousand words:

Rotate the thick blue line around the red point.
(Of course if the initial line is not parallel to the line defined by the two points, just rotate the line around the unique intersection between the line and the line defined by the two points.)


Of course... TWO rotations.  But one as well.

It can be solved with one rotation if the rotation can be out of the plane.

Also with a single rotation 0f 180º inside the plane, around the center of the rectangle that has the two points as vertices, and a segment of the line as one of its sides (as per @M0M0's comment above)

180 degree rotation about an axis halfway between line and the line formed by the 2 points.

I am assuming the 2 points and line are coplanar.
You want to consider 2 cases here:
(1) line is parallel to line formed by the 2 points.
(2) any other case has an intersection between the line and the line formed by the two points.
For (1), you can pick a point that is halfway between these two parallel lines and which lies on the perpendicular bisector of the segment on the two points.  Using this as an axis of rotation, you can rotate the line 180 degrees to have the 2 points on it.
(2) is simpler; find this point of intersection, and you can rotate the line about that point to get them to be coincident.

Why would you assume the two points and the line are coplanar? The interesting case is the opposite.

@TedShifrin, the question asked is not clear, but that is what I believe OP is asking, since the previous post OP refers to is coplanar.
The case where the 2 lines are skew is certainly interesting.

Yeah, I apologize. I had assumed it was a 3D question because the 2D case seemed obvious to me. But the linked question, I now see, dealt with 2D.

Yeah, for the case of skew, there won't be one, if you keep all rotations in the 3-d space that the line and points exist in.  If you allow a rotation in 4-d space which the 3-d space is embedded in, it might work.
